# Meta tag "width=device-width" error with bookmarked pages

Tags: html, mobile-website, screen-resolution

My website http://www.janewaltonwatercolours.co.uk is working fine on the whole, apart from one small and annoying problem - When I bookmark the website on my mobile and then return to the bookmark later, it doesn't appear to recognise the correct width of the device (despite a meta tag with the code 'width=device-width') and inadvertently loads the wrong stylesheet. (it loads the desktop.css instead of mobile.css - I have a script that should determine the correct stylesheet by using the screen.width property)

Strangely, if you refresh the screen straightaway it reloads the page with the correct stylesheet?! So i thought it might be a cache issue, with the incorrect html/css page being loaded from memory for some reason, but I've tried playing around with the .htaccess file with no success.

I've since noticed some links to pages also load incorrectly, so its not just bookmarked pages that don't work.

Any ideas? Is it a problem with the meta tag? Any help greatly appreciated!

Mike

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0):

Fixed - After more searching I found some information on meta tags sometimes not being read before scripts run, and the screen resolution of the previous page is used instead.

So i wrapped my function in a setTimeout function - setTimeout('getDeviceWidth',100); this delays the function by 100ms ensuring the meta tag code 'width=device-width' has completed